# UIScrollView view bounces back and doesn't stay at bottom

Tags: ios, ios7, uiview, uiscrollview

I have this set:

```
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 1000.0)];
scroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 1000.0);

[self.view addSubview:scroll];

UIView *pView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 100.0, 300.0, 400.0)];
pView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
pView.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0;
pView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
pView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;

[scroll addSubview:pView];

UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 500.0, 300.0, 20.0)];
aView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[scroll addSubview:aView];
```

But everytime I scroll down on the view, the screen bounces back up to the top. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't set your scrollview height larger than your screen size - it's NOT the scrollView that scrolls, it's the content IN the scrollview.

Comment: You dont give a real solution. What gets the height? For example: <ScrollView> takes up 40% of my overall <View> but has lots and lots of <Text> inside. When I scroll down, it bounces back up. If I set ScrollView's styled height to 800 (it seems that it just has to be a value larger than the height of the child elements in total), I can scroll to the bottom and it stays there. So your answer is not correct either for most or all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your scroll view height, Pls check your UIScrollView height, it will greater than your screen size

```
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, viewHeight)];
```